# How to import userpoints?

Tags: 7, migrations, userpoints

The [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module doesn't have migrate integration yet.
Looking at the API I can probably use [userpoints_service_add](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x--userpoints_service.inc/function/userpoints_service_add/7-1) to assign "starting point" values for each user in a batch script.

Is there an option to update the "starting point" value for a user when I go live? Or do I have to calculate the difference and just add an adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [userpoints_userpointsapi()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x--userpoints.module/function/userpoints_userpointsapi/7-1), not the service wrapper.

The system is designed to only ever allow new transactions in order to change the total amount of points a user has. So yes, if you want to set it to a fixed value, you need to calculate the difference from the actual amount of points a user has and grant him the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you could do this with the [data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module to expose you old tables to views. Then using [views bulk operations](http://drupal.org/project/vbo) and [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to copy the userpoints to the new users.

I am curious what are you migrating from? Doesn't userpoints have an upgrade path?

Comment: thanks. I'm importing from an external system, I had to pull the data through their API and now have it stored in mysql tables. Most of the content I could import using the migrate module. For some I'm running scripts

Answer (score 0):

These days there is a [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) integration available for [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints), as confirmed also in the User Points issue "[Migration support for User Points](https://www.drupal.org/node/689702)".

[Comment nr 17](https://www.drupal.org/node/689702#comment-8828181) in it includes a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/userpoints_migrate-689702-17.patch), which according to [Comment nr 18 of that issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/689702#comment-9660437) works perfectly.

And as per [Comment nr 21 of that issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/689702#comment-9884323), it's [included in the 7.x-1.1 release](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/userpoints/tree/userpoints.migrate.inc?h=7.x-1.x).